# Autohotkey to convert dot "." to space

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I am looking for a simple AutoHotkey Code to convert dot "." of file name to space Example `Hamburger.Hill.1987.BluRay.720p.x264` needs to be converted to `Hamburger Hill 1987 BluRay 720p x264`.

Start with string: `Hamburger.Hill.1987.BluRay.720p.x264.mov`

Result String: `Hamburger Hill 1987 BluRay 720p x264.mov`

Note the dot before the extension should be retained.

Then in a separate operation, remove the string of characters following the 4 digit year. This operation should also remove the file extension.

Start with string: `Hamburger Hill 1987 BluRay 720p x264.mov`

Result String: `Hamburger Hill 1987.mov`

Here is my code

```
#.:: ; Replace all "." (except before extension) with spaces 
OldCLip := ClipboardAll 
Clipboard := "" 
Send ^c 
ClipWait, .2 
; MsgBox % Clipboard    ; for testing 

if Clipboard FileMove, % Clipboard, % RegExReplace(Clipboard, "\.(?=.*?\.[^.]+$)", " ") 
Clipboard := OldClip 
return
```

I looked throughly but could not see code related to this. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/yP4bY4/1) could help you to clean the titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AutoHotKey you'd use something like this:

```
; set the value
String := "Hamburger.Hill.1987.BluRay.720p.x264.mov"

; capture the extension
RegexMatch(String, "(.*)(\.[^.]*?$)", SubPart)
Filename := SubPart1
Extension := SubPart2

; replace all the dots with spaces
Output1 := RegexReplace(Filename, "\.", " ")

; remove the unwanted characters after the year
Output2 := RegexReplace(Output1, "(?<=\d{4}).*", "")

strMessage := ""
, strMessage .= "String  = '" . String . "'
, strMessage .= "`nOutput1 = '" . Output1 . Extension "'
, strMessage .= "`nOutput2 = '" . Output2 . Extension "'
MsgBox, % strMessage
```

Sample output

```
String  = 'Hamburger.Hill.1987.BluRay.720p.x264.mov'
Output1 = 'Hamburger Hill 1987 BluRay 720p x264.mov'
Output2 = 'Hamburger Hill 1987.mov'
```

---

## How I would incorporate that into your script.

```
#.:: ; Replace all "." (except before extension) with spaces 
OldCLip := ClipboardAll 
Clipboard=
Send ^c
ClipWait
; MsgBox % Clipboard    ; for testing 

; set the value
String := Clipboard
; String := "Hamburger.Hill.1987.BluRay.720p.x264.mov"

; capture the extension
RegexMatch(String, "(.*)(\.[^.]*?$)", SubPart)
Filename := SubPart1
Extension := SubPart2

; replace all the dots with spaces
Output1 := RegexReplace(Filename, "\.", " ")

; remove the unwanted characters after the year
Output2 := RegexReplace(Output1, "(?<=\d{4}).*", "")

; strMessage := ""
; , strMessage .= "String  = '" . String . "'
; , strMessage .= "`nOutput1 = '" . Output1 . Extension "'
; , strMessage .= "`nOutput2 = '" . Output2 . Extension "'
; MsgBox, % strMessage

if ( String ) { 
    strMessage := "Renaming '" . Output1 . Extension . "' to '" . Output2 . Extension . "'"
    MsgBox, % strMessage
    FileMove, % Output1 . Extension, % Output2 . Extension
    } ; end if

Clipboard := OldClip 
return
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. It does also remove the "." before extension. Is there any way to exclude "." before extension? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Thanks Denomales. Its working now. Just wondering  if it's further possible to trim anything after the  4 digit year (e.g. Hamburger Hill 1987) only and trim BluRay 720p.x264? Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: Thanks. The Output2 again also remove the "." before extension. Is there way to combine into one regex expression?

Comment: Updated answer to cover the your lates revision. It's not possible to both replace characters with a space and replace other characters with nothing in a single operation. Regex does not work that way. In this update I've decided that it would be better to separate the fileaname from the extension so that it can be reassembled by you on request. This also simplifies the search and replace process.
If you have additional changes please include the exact value of the start string and the exact value you'd like returned. Your original question and comments are murky on the topic of extension.

Comment: Showing error in output 1 while I try to use in AHK code. No addition change require. What I need is exactly as shown in your sample output. But I am unable to use latest version in my AHK code because output2 also remove the extension even if use in two stage as you showed. Still OK with your previous version.

Comment: I've updated my answer again, and edited your question to include all these conditions.

Comment: AHK showing error "Too many parameters passed to function. Arrow to line RegexMatch(String, "(.*)(\.[^.]*?$)", "",,SubPart)"

Comment: Ah there's the problem, [RegexMatch](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm) parameters are out of order.

Comment: It showing renaming msg output1 to output2 but does not execute rename of file.

Comment: Autohotkey commend `filemove` assumes the files are in script's working directory. If the files are not there, then it's not going to work as coded. You'll likely need to include the full path to the files. However, this new question is beyond the scope of the original question regarding search and replacing. Since I've provided that answer and demonstrated it does the replacement as expected,  then please accept the answer. To move forward with this new problem, please open a new question in StackExchange, and I'd be happy to continue there.

Comment: Its almost at the end of development, just need to find a way to rename the file. Nevertheless I am considering it as a answers at it's current stage. Little effort would make it perfect answer more than the original asked problem.

Comment: To make it work with the full path you have to already know what the full path is. Your original question and these followup comments have not provided any information about where the full path should be.

Comment: Don't understand the last question. My requirement is just to change the file name in same directory (e.g D:\Any Folder\Sub Folder\Hamburger.Hill.1987.BluRay.720p.x264.mov
to
D:\Any Folder\Sub Folder\Hamburger Hill 1987.mov

Comment: StackoverFlow is a question/answer site, not a code on demand site. To help answer the new requirement you should really post it as a new question, something like "Using AutoHotKey, I'm trying to rename files, but the files aren't getting renamed." and you should provide samples of your code. To help you further you should reference [this web page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I posted as a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089063/rename-file-remove-unnecesary-character-using-autohotkey)