# VBA Solution for quick rename of active office document file (Word, Excel, PowerPoint)

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

File rename is often requires while working on Microsoft Office Suite applications (Word, Excel, PowerPoint).  Usually “Files > Save as” allows rename the file but it also create duplication since the original file remain there and there is no simultaneous options to delete the original file. Although this option is currently in practice but for quick and convenient rename without any duplication of same file the current available option is not adequate. Close the file, remember its name and locate that file in the residing specific directory (where file is masked by similar other files) is possible but the approach is very time consuming and not a good solution to improve productivity.

Obviously that leads to need of a single click quick option which would allow rename of the file which would also delete the old file or overwrite on existing file. AFAIK the Office suite applications / Windows explorer does not allow renames the file while it opens (file locked). So to my understanding and reading from other similar questions in this forum this is might be technical limitation and might not possible to rename active (locked) file. However I have seen a solution of this kind in Sumatra PDF reader where the file is PDF and pressing F2 button allows not only rename but also option to choose the folder where to keep the renamed file (original folder or elsewhere) without any duplication of file. I am looking forward if their similar VBA commands which would do at least rename the file at original location or some sort of automation in rename process which avoid duplication and/or minimize the efforts necessary to rename. Searched but could not see any Office suite native built-in shortcut key/command to automate the rename process. Closest I found VBA command `Shell Environ("windir") & "\Explorer.exe " & ActiveDocument.Path, vbMaximizedFocus` allow to locate the folder location only of currently opened file but it does not select/highlight that specific file and difficult to distinguish if there similar other files in that folder. Thanks in advance for your support contribution.

Comment: @KenWhite -- In fact Rhinemine asked two questions in one. The other question you linked in was answered and accepted by them. Then there were some comments on an alternate solution, so I told them to ask a new question for the other question she wants handled.

Comment: @ib11: Then the second question should be phrased differently, should clearly ask a different question, and should have a title that describes a different aspect or issue. I read this as the same question based on all three of those things. It asks about renaming a currently open Office document using AHK or VBA, just as the other question does.  It should be edited to make it clearly different. When it has been, I'll be glad to retract my close vote.

Comment: @Rhinemine, please reword your question so that it is clear that it is different.

Comment: I have reworded the both questions differently aimed to  demonstrate that those are different issue and also different or alternate solution. First question aimed to find way to locate the file while path is given using AHK code. The second question aimed to rename on-the-fly of office document using VBA code. Off course there are alternate solution for apparently similar issues but it would be nice to have both solution because one might better than other in some cases as each of has some unique advantage and limitations.

Comment: Although I have limited knowledge of AHK but I found is good for handling explorer files, user friendly customization, cross-programs maneuver while VBA might better solution because of its built-in native nature in office applications or using in a PC where AHK is not available. Also it would be better to get contribution from different member of this forum who is expertise in one language tool (VBA) than the other (AHK). Although I am very new in stack and in learning curve but I had no implied or expressed intention of getting more attention by posting two separate questions of same issue.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I hope @KenWhite will also be okay with them now.

Comment: @ib11: Yes, as I said before, I was glad to retract my close vote once the questions were in fact clearly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach is not via the Explorer shell, instead:

- 1) Store the full path of the document in a string: `oldfile = ActiveDocument.FullName`
- 2) SaveAs the document with `ActiveDocument.SaveAs`
- 3) Delete the old file with `Kill oldfile`

All this is from VBA directly, no need to use Explorer shell.

Below are the full codes for all three applications, with prompting the SaveAs dialog, but then also deleting the old file.

You can use this to rename the Excel document:

```
Sub RenameActiveWorkBook()

    Dim oldfile As String

    Set myWbook = ActiveWorkbook

    If myWbook.Path = "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        myWbook.Save
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '1) store current file
    oldfile = myWbook.FullName

    '2) save as the active document (prompt user for file name)
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).InitialFileName = oldfile
    If Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Execute
    If oldfile = myWbook.FullName Then Exit Sub
    'ONLY RENAME: myWbook.SaveAs Filename:=myWbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & InputBox("Enter new name", "Rename current document", myWbook.Name), AddToMru:=True

    '3) Delete the old file with
    On Error GoTo FileLocked
    Kill oldfile
    On Error GoTo 0

    Exit Sub

FileLocked:
    MsgBox "Could not delete " & oldfile, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "File is locked"

End Sub
```

And very similar to this is the PPT:

```
Sub RenameActivePresentation()

    Dim oldfile As String

    Set myPPT = ActivePresentation

    If myPPT.Path = "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show
        Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Execute
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '1) store current file
    oldfile = myPPT.FullName

    '2) save as the active document (prompt user for file name)
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).InitialFileName = oldfile
    If Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Execute
    If oldfile = myPPT.FullName Then Exit Sub
    'ONLY RENAME: myPPT.SaveAs FileName:=myPPT.Path & "\" & InputBox("Enter new name", "Rename current document", myPPT.Name)

    '3) Delete the old file with
    On Error GoTo FileLocked
    Kill oldfile
    On Error GoTo 0

    Exit Sub

FileLocked:
    MsgBox "Could not delete " & oldfile, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "File is locked"

End Sub
```

And just to have it complete, here is the Word macro for the same thing:

```
Sub RenameActiveDoc()

    Dim oldfile As String

    Set myDoc = ActiveDocument

    If myDoc.Path = "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        myDoc.Save
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '1) store current file
    oldfile = myDoc.FullName

    '2) save as the active document (prompt user for file name)
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).InitialFileName = oldfile
    If Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Execute
    If oldfile = myDoc.FullName Then Exit Sub
    'ONLY RENAME: myDoc.SaveAs FileName:=myDoc.Path & Application.PathSeparator & InputBox("Enter new name", "Rename current document", myDoc.Name)

    '3) Delete the old file with
    On Error GoTo FileLocked
    Kill oldfile
    On Error GoTo 0

    Exit Sub

FileLocked:
    MsgBox "Could not delete " & oldfile, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "File is locked"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @ib11 for sharing with two beautiful code. It changes my understanding so far I have about rename of locked file. I tried few times and found it very amazing. I up vote already and would be glad to flag it as answer but I would keep it as for a little while. A quick observation I could imagine future upgrade if it could include features like browsing folder where to keep the rename file (just like save as)

Comment: To have a browse function, you can use the `Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)`. It gives you access to the SaveAs dialog. You can explore it and use the help and see where you get with it.

Comment: Hello @ib11, I tried Word and Excel VBA few times today. I sadly noticed in most instances it rename but forcefully take the file to last saved location folder or my document folder. It should save in the original folder where the file was before. Please check the code, hopefully you would be able to fix it or add browse function to let user define where to save. Right now user have no control to choose where to save and it does not save in original folder either. Thanks

Comment: Try to change this line: `myDoc.SaveAs FileName:=myDoc.Path & Application.PathSeparator & InputBox("Enter new name", "Rename current document", myDoc.Name)` This will force saving to the same folder as your current document is saved at. I updated the codes.

Comment: Word and Excel seem to be OK in few trial. But PPT showing error. Highlighted word .PathSeparator and later message code Compile Error, method or data member not found

Comment: @Rhinemine Funny how not smart PPT is compared to XL and WD. Anyway, I fixed the code. Also as you note, all 3 scripts now check if the file was ever saved and if not, they prompt the user to Save As. The PPT code has the `FileDialog` you asked earlier, see if you can incorporate it in the SaveAs section.

Comment: Thanks. PPT FileDialogue get active when file was not previously saved or new draft. Tricky would be if that can add to every document/sheet/presentation. I am not confident that at my current knowledge level in VBA I would be able to figure out how to add Dialogs `wdDialogFileSaveAs` in the above VBA script. Nevertheless I would try but certainly welcome your contribution once again.

Comment: @Rhinemine OK, I did them. I hope you like it.

Comment: Wonderful! Like it much. Thanks.

Comment: BTW you can also assign a shortcut key to them, like F2 as you mentioned. Or, **if you call the macro `FileSaveAs` then you will replace the default Save As function (F12) with this code!** So all save as will remove the old file. Check out this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837542.aspx